# Azure media services - how to get video resolution?

Tags: video, azure, metadata

Is there a way to retrieve some metadata about the videos uploaded to Azure's Media Services, like their resolution, format, codecs or bitrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The closest type to your request is [IAssetFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mediaservices.client.iassetfile.aspx) which represents a single file within an asset. But it does not contain any media meta data.

In its current form Windows Azure Media Services is not designed to be fully feature media content management system. But rather an easy-to-use service for media transformation, (live) and on-demand streaming.

If you want to keep track of media meta data you have to build your own media CMS on top of Azure Media Services and inspect all uploaded assets before submitting them to the Media Services. This is the only way to track/save media meta-data as of today.